# C - Recursive call to traverse sub-directory and print all files + sizes (using stat)

Tags: c, size, byte, long-integer, stat

I have a program that recursively prints the cwd size plus containing file sizes and repeats for each sub directory.

---

Recursive directory traversal function: (Note the reason for printf in this function and passing two strings is that the output needs to be in a special format so I can't just output the actual filepath. Also I am just learning about system calls to work with directories in ubuntu so if you have any comments on improvements on the code I would appreciate them (style or using something more simple to accomplish the same).

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TRUE 1 
#define FALSE 0
#define FIRST_ARG 1
#define SECOND_ARG 2
char* fileName;
FILE* fileToRead;
DIR* directoryToRead;
int printFileSize(char*);
int printWorkingSize(char*, char*);
int printSize(char*, char*);
int printDir(char*, char*);
int printCurrentDir(char*, char*);
int bytesToKbytes(long long, char*);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc == FIRST_ARG) {
        char currentDir[PATH_MAX + 1] = "";
        char* currentDirectory;
        directoryToRead = opendir (".");
        if (directoryToRead == NULL){
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        closedir(directoryToRead);
        printCurrentDir(currentDirectory, ".");
    }
return 0;
}

int printCurrentDir(char* name, char* path) {
    struct dirent *dir;
    struct stat statBuffer;
    char fileName[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char filePath[PATH_MAX + 1];
    DIR* openDir;
    if((openDir = opendir(path)) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open %s\n", path);
    }    
    stat(path, &statBuffer);
    if(strcmp(path, ".") == 0) {
        printf("%lld .\n", (long long)statBuffer.st_size);
    }   else {
            printf("%lld %s\n", (long long)statBuffer.st_size, name);
    }
    while (TRUE) {  // go through contents of current directory
        dir = readdir(openDir);
        if(!dir) {
            break;
        }
        if((strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") == 0) || (strcmp(dir->d_name,".") == 0)) {
            continue;
        }
        if(name == NULL) {
            strcpy(fileName, dir->d_name);
        } else {
        strcpy(fileName, name);
        strcat(fileName, "/");
        strcat(fileName, dir->d_name);
        }
        strcpy(filePath, path);
        strcat(filePath, "/");
        strcat(filePath, dir->d_name);
        if(dir->d_type == DT_DIR) {  // if the next file is a directory
            if(!printCurrentDir(fileName, filePath)) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } 
        else if(!printWorkingSize(fileName, filePath)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

//output file size in bytes followed by name-> (char* file)
int printWorkingSize(char* file, char* path) {
    struct stat statBuffer;
    stat(path, &statBuffer);
    char result[PATH_MAX];
    if(bytesToKbytes((long long)statBuffer.st_size, result) == FALSE) {
        sprintf(result, "%lld", (long long)statBuffer.st_size);
    }
    printf("%5s %s\n", result, path);
    return TRUE;
        }


// convert bytes to kilobytes if more than 5 digits
int bytesToKbytes(long long bytes, char* result) {
    if(!(bytes > 99999)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    char size[PATH_MAX];
    sprintf(size, "%lld", bytes);
    size[3] = 'K';
    size[4] = '\0';
    strcpy(result, size);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Ok. I probably missed something, but wouldn't it be much easier to just compare `if (bytes > 10000)` , *then* convert the actual *number* to kilobytes, then `sprintf` to the target buffer, rather than playing with char buffer manipulation?

Comment: How about `int kbytes = bytes/1024`?

Comment: @RSahu that would be a [*kibibyte*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) , not kilobyte translation. The idea is certainly correct, however.

Comment: @WhozCraig I want to output the exact string "xyzK"  where x,y,z is the first 3 numbers in the bytes followed by a K and cutting off all the rest of the values. Also I tried doing (bytes >= 100000) but it would always return true even if they were less for some reason. Figured it was something to do with long long messing up the comparison to int

Comment: I would have liked to have seen that code, and I assume you meant `10000` not `100000`. The *real* current code would be nice to see, as what is posted here won't compile, and thus cannot produce the output specified. Ex: `bytesToKbytes((long long bytes)statBuffer.st_size, result);`isn't valid C. `bytes` has no apparent business being in that statement.

Comment: @WhozCraig so the conditional compares length of number instead of the number itself? comparing bytes to 100,000 would return true only if bytes had 7 digits? (1,000,000) instead of returning true if bytes was 100,001?

Comment: No, if `100000` were your test value, then it would eval true if the bytes had **six** or more digits. `99999` is five digits, anything larger is six (or more). Likewise `9999` is four digits, anything larger is five (or more). Thus if you want to convert to kilobytes if the value is 5 digits long or longer, then `if (bytes >= 10000)` or `if (bytes > 9999)` would both accomplish what you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig ah sorry bad wording in the title, I meant over 5 digits as is (bytes > 5) not (bytes >= 5) so only convert to kbytes if it has 6 digits or more.

I will try and get the original code and edit it in (had modified it to make it more readable)

Comment: Eh. could be read either way. No worries. `if (bytes > 99999)` is pretty straight forward. I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is operating system specific. On Linux and [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix), you should simply use the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) library function, which is recursively reading the directories and already calling [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is effectively in the way you use `bytesToKbytes`. It returns a boolean to indicate if it wrote anything in result and :

- you do not preload anything in result before calling `bytesToKbytes`
- you do not test return value to write anything in resul if size was less than 99999

You could use :

```
int printWorkingSize(char* file, char* path) {
    struct stat statBuffer;
    stat(path, &statBuffer);
    char result[PATH_MAX];
    if (! bytesToKbytes((long long)statBuffer.st_size, result)) {
        sprintf(result, "%lld", (long long)statBuffer.st_size);
    }
    printf("%5s %s\n", result, path);
    return TRUE;
}
```

You could also change `bytesToKbytes` to put length in bytes into resul if size is less than 99999

Comment: Thanks you! That was definitely a big oversight. The Recursive call in printCurrentDir() still has the problem where is doesn't output the files in some deeper sub-directories. Can anyone tell me why its not listing every file in every sub-directory of the cwd?